# environ.SDK_VERSION removed in App Engine 1.7.6?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I've updated to latest App Engine for Python 1.7.6 but the SDK_VERSION os environ variable seems to be gone...

I'm using Django 1.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, as acknowledged by GAE team: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9073